# Minimum Pulse Width for asynchronous Interrupt

Tags: gpio

Does anybody know what is the shortest pulse width that the Raspberry Pi (any model) GPIO interrupt pins can detect? I have a project in mind, but the pulses would be between 5 & 17ns wide.

Answer (score 3):

The GPIO peripheral is identical on all Pi models.  The only difference is  in the number of GPIO routed to the expansion header.

The Pi has a `GPIO Asynchronous rising/falling Edge Detect` mode.

See pages 99/100 of [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf).

"Asynchronous means the incoming signal is not sampled by the system clock. As such rising/falling edges of very short duration can be detected."

I'm fairly sure that 4ns will be detected.

I don't know if this mode is the Pi default.  You will have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

As joan has said this should be possible. 5ns corresponds to 100MHz and should be within the Pi capabilities. 
Your problem will be delivering the signal. A terminated transmission line would be required.